# Log Clean up for SVN repo

Tags: svn

There is a log file for SVN present as below,

```
    $ pwd
    /var/svn/repositories/axs/hooks/commitlog/
    $ ls -lh errorlog
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache 6.9M Jul 22 18:37 errorlog
    $ cat errorlog |wc -l
    68151
```

Since number of lines in this file are more, i need to clean up this file, 
Clean up should be in this way, Before clean up i need to back up this file with current date and then empty the current file.

Below is what i had idea of,

1. Using logrotate - **The server didn't have logrotate installed**
2. Writing a script for backup and delete - **Deleting the file may cause problems to other users if they do a code commit during my delete operation**

What is the method advisable for this. Kindly suggest. For your information i am not a sudo user or admin user.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard Subversion logfile but rather appears to be one created by a [hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) installed & managed by your repo admin.

You need to speak with your repository administrator. That individual should be able to give you guidance on how best to manage this file.

Comment: Consider it as a normal log tile and tell me what needs to be done,

Comment: @Syed no one here can tell you what needs to be done. You **must** talk to whomever set up the process that's creating the file in the first place. But perhaps a better question is why do you think you need to "clean up" this file. 6.9M isn't exactly a large amount of space being consumed.